# Matlab hist function for image data

Tags: image, matlab, function, image-processing, plot

I'm new to Matlab and I want to make  my own function that makes the same job as imhist(Displays histogram of image data) but I am a total newbie to this and I don't have any clues how I'm going to develop such function..
I started making something but its very incomplete.

```
function [ output_args ] = myhist( x )
%MYHIST Summary of this function goes here
%Detailed explanation goes here

x=imread('flower.jpg');

imshow(x);

[c,d]=hist(x(:),0:1:255);
figure,plot(d,c);
figure,plot(c,d);

%figure,imhist(x);
 end
```

I would be very grateful if you could give me any helpful tips..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt at implementing the [IMHIST](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imhist.html) function. It does not handle all the cases that the official function does, but it should produce very similar results in most cases:

```
function myimhist(img)
    img = im2uint8(img);

    [count,bin] = hist(img(:), 0:255);
    stem(bin,count, 'Marker','none')

    hAx = gca;
    set(hAx, 'XLim',[0 255], 'XTickLabel',[], 'Box','on')

    %# create axes, and draw grayscale colorbar
    hAx2 = axes('Position',get(hAx,'Position'), 'HitTest','off');
    image(0:255, [0 1], repmat(linspace(0,1,256),[1 1 3]), 'Parent',hAx2)
    set(hAx2, 'XLim',[0 255], 'YLim',[0 1], 'YTick',[], 'Box','on')

    %# resize the axis to make room for the colorbar
    set(hAx, 'Units','pixels')
    p = get(hAx, 'Position');
    set(hAx, 'Position',[p(1) p(2)+26 p(3) p(4)-26])
    set(hAx, 'Units','normalized')

    %# position colorbar at bottom
    set(hAx2, 'Units','pixels')
    p = get(hAx2, 'Position');
    set(hAx2, 'Position',[p(1:3) 26])
    set(hAx2, 'Units','normalized')

    %# link x-limits of the two axes
    linkaxes([hAx;hAx2], 'x')
    set(gcf, 'CurrentAxes',hAx)
end
```

Let's test it with a sample image:

```
I = imread('coins.png');
figure(1), myimhist(I), title('myimhist')
figure(2), imhist(I), title('imhist')
```

[image: myimhist]
[image: imhist]

Note how IMHIST is apparently adjusting the y-limit so as to deal with the two different peaks in the histogram.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your goal. Try replacing

```
figure,plot(d,c);
```

with

```
figure,bar(d,c);
```