# dohist on a double - matlab

Tags: image, matlab, histogram

how do i convert an image represented as double into an image that i can use to produce a histogram?

(with dohist:)

```
% computes the histogram of a given image into num bins.
% values less than 0 go into bin 1, values bigger than 255
% go into bin 255
% if show=0, then do not show. Otherwise show in figure(show)


function thehist = dohist(theimage,show)

  % set up bin edges for histogram

  edges = zeros(256,1);
  for i = 1 : 256;
    edges(i) = i-1;
  end

  [R,C] = size(theimage);
  imagevec = reshape(theimage,1,R*C);      % turn image into long array
  thehist = histc(imagevec,edges)';        % do histogram

  if show > 0
      figure(show)
      clf
      pause(0.1)
      plot(thehist)
      axis([0, 256, 0, 1.1*max(thehist)])
  end
```

Comment: for converting the image from `double` to `uint8` look into the [IM2UINT8](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2uint8.html) function. For what it's worth, here is an example showing how to implement an image histogram function: [matlab hist function for image data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401189/matlab-hist-function-for-image-data/7493632#7493632)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you just need to normalize your image first, to do this you can use:

```
255*(theimage./(max(theimage(:)));
```

Comment: sorry i'm an idiot - i didn't have my function 'dohist' saved in the right place!
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, you could make sure the bounds get treated correctly with:

```
theimage(theimage<0) = 0;
theimage(theimage>255) = 255;
```

But this shouldnt be necessary, usually you either get a double image ranging [0,1] or uint8 [0,255] when you read an image with `imread()`. Just rescale to [0,255] in this case if needed.

Some other tips:

You can make the edges-vector like this:

```
edges = 0:255;
```

And `theimage(:)` is the same as `reshape(theimage,1,R*C)` in this case since you want one long vector.

Comment: sorry i'm an idiot - i didn't have my function 'dohist' saved in the right place!
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The built-in function `hist` can be applied directly to images of class `double`.

[Matlab documentation link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html)

If you have an image which you suspect to have N bits of resolution on the interval [A,B], you can call `hist` directly on the image (without conversion) like:

```
[H,bins] = hist(IM,linspace(A,B,2^N));
```

to retrieve the histogram and bins or

```
hist(IM,linspace(A,B,2^N));
```

to simply plot the histogram.